# How to hide files from getting pushed to Github but still have them push to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github, oauth

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I'm using OAuth2 in a heroku app that also has a public github repo. If I exclude the file that has the OAuth2 credentials via the .gitignore, will that file still get pushed to the Heroku app? If not, what's the ebst way to keep the credentials from getting published on github, but still have access to them in my heroku app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Heroku app settings to store your credentials.

```
heroku config:set KEY=VALUE
```

and then your app has an environment variable `KEY` with the specified value.

Or if you prefer you can update them through the Heroku Dashboard on the 'Settings' tab press the 'Reveal Config Vars' button and then you can edit the config variables through the web.

Comment: Okay, will I still be able to use the OAuth client on my local server if I do it that way, or will it only work on heroku ?

Comment: I don't know how your OAuth client picks up its configuration, but I would make the code check whether it can pick up the credentials from environment variables and if not fall back on the configuration file.

Comment: How do I get my Node JS file to see these keys? `const config = require('./config');` works on my local machine, but not in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the above solution worked fine. In my case I just did

```sh
heroku config:add KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2
```

The only thing is to separate multiple values with a space I guess :)